# sh: php command not found error from web browser

Tags: php, shell, ubuntu, command

I have one file with code

```
 shell_exec (php test.php)
```

When I run this file from command prompt, It run successfully and when same file I am trying to run through web browser this will give error as

```
 sh: php command not found.
```

what can be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was with php path. so I have done like this

```
 if(defined('PHP_BINARY') && PHP_BINARY) 
  {
    $path = PHP_BINARY . '/php'; //PHP >= 5.4
  }
 else if(defined('PHP_BINDER') && PHP_BINDER)
  {
    $path = PHP_BINDER . '/php'; //PHP < 5.4
  }
else
  {
    //Throws Exception 
  }
```

and then used this variable in shell command as

```
   shell_exec ($path test.php)
```

Answer (score 0):

could you please provide the information which webserver you're using ? 
If you are using apache you might install *libapache2-mod-php7.0* for php7.

ToDo this *apt* comes in handy:

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

or try to activate it

```
sudo a2enmod php7.0
```

Make sure that the php files are marked executable for webserver user (e.g. www-data)

```
sudo chmod -R o+x *.php
```